# Adding a non mergeable branch like gh-pages

Tags: git, github

I like how `gh-pages` is just a branch of a repository. I want to create a new branch to store things that related to a repository, but should not be updated very often, so I don't want to store inside the master branch.

Like `gh-pages`, I would like to create an `example` branch, that won't ever be offered to merge. Ideally I don't want the message below to be available:

[image: what I would like to prevent.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. But why are you disturbed? It's just a message. If you create a `gh-pages` branch, the message is hidden but you can do a pull request.

Comment: I wanted to create something that should not be packed, but I switched approach and modified my packaging scripts. Thank you.